# How to bring my google map embed code for mobile device correctly for mobile device

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, iframe

can any one help me, the map has taking space in right side, how to solve that,I am Having issue  with  my google map embed for mobile device. If you see my output in webserver, map is not perfectly sitting,right side have so much of space, here is the link, please check, I dont know where i am wrong.  http://lotusvalue.com/index1.html

```
<div class="agile-contact1">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6" style="padding-left:30px;"><img src="imagesnew/imagelog3.png" class="img-responsive"><br/>
<p>#2112, 3rd Floor, 9th Main, 15th Cross,<br/>
D' Block,Sahakar Nagar Bengaluru - 560092.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6"><iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3886.6139875875365!2d77.58402861482297!3d13.060225090797745!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3bae1821ca8b1d9f%3A0x8fd257ca32720efd!2sLotus+Value+Developers!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1543592662682" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</div><!--endofcontainer-->
</div><!--endofrow-->
</div><!--endofagile-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: in your index2.html page... replace your iframe div with the 2 divs in the code-snippet below; These 2 divs basically do this:

```
 1. First div with 500px map which displays on desktop/tablet only and hides in mobile.
 2. Second div with 300px map which hides on desktop/tablet and displays only on mobile
```

your iframe is 300px in width... with a padding of 15px on left/right due to "col-sm-6 col-md-6"... the padding on the left is pushing the fixed-width iframe to the right side.

So, you gotta do 2 things

1. add a class soClass to the div encapsulating the iframe you gotta (like code below)
2. manage that for widths less than 330px (code snippet below)

Since the iframe map is fixed for 300px, for mobile devices less than 300px of screen width, there will be a horizontal scroll

```css
@media screen AND (max-width:330px){
.soClass{
padding: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 soClass hidden-md hidden-lg"><iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3886.6139875875365!2d77.58402861482297!3d13.060225090797745!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3bae1821ca8b1d9f%3A0x8fd257ca32720efd!2sLotus+Value+Developers!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1543592662682" style="border:0"></iframe></div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 hidden-sm  hidden-xs">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3886.6139875875365!2d77.58402861482297!3d13.060225090797745!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3bae1821ca8b1d9f%3A0x8fd257ca32720efd!2sLotus+Value+Developers!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1543580574885" width="500" height="250" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: but in desktop and laptop view i want the map  width to be  width="600" height="450", if i give ,it reflects for desktop , once again in mobile device the size is not fitting and right side space has come. how to control that

Comment: embedding google maps via iframe would mean a fixed width... to get around it, you can use google maps API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide which will give you true responsive experience; i did that for https://www.akberiqbal.com/events.htm (click moments by location on the top navigation)

Comment: check this please  in mobile not reflecting , i have embeded your code, cross check, it is not reflecting in mobile device ,http://lotusvalue.com/index2.html     @media screen and (max-width: 767px){ .soClass{
padding: 0;
} , but not reflecting

Comment: the iframe is now 500px in width and since you are looking at a mobile (of width < 500px) the iframe/map goes beyond the screen size... if you want to use embed maps... you can include 2 divs. First div with 500px map which displays on desktop/tablet only and hides in mobile. Second div with 300px map which hides on desktop/tablet and displays only on mobile

Comment: rai, I am trying this since yesterday, unable fix ,just give code, i will embed and alter, i understood the concept ,how to hide the first div when comes to mobile

Comment: yes, it's fine  check @ server http://lotusvalue.com/index3.html tell me is it fine in mobile from top to bottom